# Android : How to add possibility to move the app to external storage device

Tags: android, storage, skype

How to add the possibility in my android app to move it to external storage from app info like Skype in the screenshot.

[image: Skype app info]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can declare this line in your mainfest file,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

See the [Official Android reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#Should), you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) too

Comment: Did you try it and is it working with you ? For me it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file add the following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackagename"
    android:installLocation="auto">
```

if you set the value of `installLocation` to `auto` then user can keep the app wherever they want